# selenium geolocation that doesn't change on first search

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geolocation, webdriver

When I google "apple", the first search is always on the old location (Ankara) , but if I refresh the page, it will be on the new location (Paris). What I want is to be able to use the new location (Paris) in the first search.

[image: first search location]

[image: location after page refresh]

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == '__main__':

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #options.add_argument("--lang=en-GB")
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1})


    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


    driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
        "Emulation.setGeolocationOverride",
        {
            "latitude": 48.87645,
            "longitude": 2.26340,
            "accuracy": 100,
        },
    )

    driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=apple")
    time.sleep(1231)
```